# Loop Through Listbox in VB.net or C# and Set Values to Label Text?

Tags: c#, vb.net, loops, listbox

I have items in a listbox control that I would like to repeatedly (when it gets to the last one, repeat) loop through and set the text to a label.

I'm stuck, please help!

Comment: Could you tell us how often you want this to repeat?  Forever?  And why?

Comment: I'd like it to repeat forever. Think of it like a marquee news banner - I want to cycle the latest headlines repeatedly and set the headlines to a label. The headlines would be in the listbox control.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but the following method will continuously cycle through the items of the given ListBox, displaying the values in the given Label control, going back from the start when it reaches the end, refreshing twice a second (C# code):

```
private int _currentIndex = -1;
private void ShowNextItem(ListBox listBox, Label label)
{
    // advance the current index one step, and reset it to 0 if it
    // is beyond the number of items in the list
    _currentIndex++;
    if (_currentIndex >= listBox.Items.Count)
    {
        _currentIndex = 0;
    }

    label.Text = listBox.Items[_currentIndex].ToString();

    // get a thread from the thread pool that waits around for a given
    // time and then calls this method again
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((state) =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        this.Invoke(new Action<ListBox, Label>(ShowNextItem), listBox, label);
    });
}
```

Call it like this:

```
ShowNextItem(myListBox, myLabel);
```

Comment: Fredrik, tack så mycket! :) Worked flawlessly!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to be using eventing rather than polling in a loop.  More details are needed.